# How to get process(PID) initiated connections

Tags: linux, tcp

For example `tomcat`(PID is `4739`) is initiated connection to `postgress`(Which is another server) to retrieve data from DB because, `tomcat` got the request from client(`curl 192.168.1.12:8088/get`). In this, `tomcat` uses a random tcp `source port` to connection `postgress`. Now, is there any way to get these `source ports` that was by created tomcat `PID`.

I used `netstat -tp`, but I'm not getting `PID` of the connection. Getting `PID` only I use `l - Listening` like `netstat -tlp`. I tried to read `PID` sockets from `/proc/PID/fd` and then correlated to `/proc/net/tcp`. But I'm not seeing anything in `/proc/net/tcp`.

**NOTE:** The topology like below.

`My requests(server1)`<------->`tomcat(server2)`<-------->`postgress(server2)`

**UPDATE1**
`netstat -tepn` output

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp6       0      1 172.25.30.21:36598      xx.xx.xx.91:4343     SYN_SENT    0          42955126    9661/java
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:38340      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:38064      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:38282      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:37520      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:38286      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:37654      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:37906      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:38152      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:38124      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:37412      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:37374      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:38126      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:38252      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:37224      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:37800      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:37780      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:38274      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:37244      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:37880      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:38230      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:38118      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:37496      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:1099       172.25.30.21:47496      ESTABLISHED 0          42954824    4738/java
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:37474      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:38200      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:38102      172.25.30.12:5432       TIME_WAIT   0          0           -
```

`PID` `grep`ed output

```
veeru@localhost:~/veeru# netstat -tepn | grep 4738
tcp6       0      0 127.0.1.1:41095         127.0.0.1:45180         ESTABLISHED 0          42960213    4738/java       
tcp6       0      0 172.25.30.21:1099       172.25.30.21:49984      ESTABLISHED 0          42963153    4738/java
```

Answer (score 0):

`netstat -tep | grep <pid of server2>`

This should give you the source port used by the server2 in connecting to postgress.

Comment: humm! Interesting! But for my requirement I need `pids` for `TIME_WAIT` state also. I know `TIME_WAIT` means connection completed. I need these `client ports` and its `PID` even the connection is in `TIME_WAIT`. Is that possible?. (For `TIME_WAIT` state, it not showing any `pid`)

Comment: @Veerendra, PIDs are process identifiers.  There is no PID for each connections. So, if you grep for PID with netstat, you should be able to see all the connection states

Comment: @Pradhu Please check my updated question. As you can see for `TIME_WAIT` states, there is no `PID`.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux

- `netstat -atp`
- `ss -atp`
- `lsof -i tcp`

will give you a list of TCP sockets along with the pids (and fds except for `netcat`) of the processes that have a fd open on them (you'll need superuser privilege to get that info for processes that are not yours), but only if they do have a fd open  to them.

After processes have closed their fd to a socket, or shutdown() the connection, even if only the writing direction, it's no longer possible to get that information. You may still see sockets in some `TIME_WAIT` state in the output of `netstat` or `ss`, but AFAICT, there's no way to get back to the processes that had file descriptors on them.

Your best bet in that case may be to log all TCP connections as they happen for instance by using `auditctl` to audit log the `connect()` system calls.